# What's wrong with my isElement function (binary tree)?

Tags: haskell, binary-tree

I'm working on a a function that check whether an element is part of a binary tree. I've defined a type for my tree called `Tree`, functions to get the root element and the left and right subtrees, and a function called `isElement` for checking whether a value is into my tree. Unfortunately, the function only works with the root element.

The following example illustrates the incorrect results I get from my `isElement` function:

```hs
*Main>let tree = Node 1 Empty (Node 2 Empty (Node 3 Empty Empty))
*Main> isElement  tree 2
False
*Main> isElement  tree 3
False
*Main> isElement  tree 1
True
```

This is my code:

```hs
data Tree a = Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) 
        |Empty
        deriving (Show)

nodeValue :: Tree t -> t
nodeValue (Node x _ _) = x

rightTree :: Tree t -> Tree t
rightTree (Node _ _ x) = x

leftTree :: Tree t -> Tree t
leftTree (Node _ x _) = x

isNode ::  Tree t -> Bool 
isNode (Node _ _ _) = True
isNode _ = False

isElement :: (Eq t) => Tree t -> t -> Bool
isElement tree t
    |isNode tree == False = False 
    | nodeValue(tree) == t = True
    | otherwise = (isElement (leftTree(tree)) t) || (isElement (leftTree(tree)) t)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a mistake in the definition of your `isElement` function: you're calling `leftTree` twice, instead of calling both `leftTree` and `rightTree`. As a result, right subtrees are never explored. Amend the code accordingly,

```hs
isElement tree t
    |isNode tree == False = False 
    | nodeValue(tree) == t = True
    | otherwise = (isElement (leftTree(tree)) t) || (isElement (rightTree(tree))
```

and then `isElement` works as advertised:

```hs
λ> let tree = Node 1 Empty (Node 2 Empty (Node 3 Empty Empty))
λ> isElement tree 2
True
λ> isElement tree 3
True
λ> isElement tree 1
True
```

However, there is still room for improvement. You don't really need all those functions (`isNode`, `nodeValue`, etc.) to define `isElement`. Instead, you can do all that unpacking with pattern matching, by breaking down the definition into two equations: one corresponding to the case where the tree is empty, and another corresponding to the case where the tree is a node:

```hs
isElement :: (Eq a) => Tree a -> a -> Bool
isElement Empty        _ = False
isElement (Node v l r) x = v == x || isElement l x || isElement r x
```

**Edit**: as pointed out by Luis Casillas in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30620638/whats-wrong-with-my-iselement-function-binary-tree/30620908#comment49326745_30620908), an additional benefit of this alternative definition is that it lends itself better (than the original definition) to *exhaustiveness checking* by the compiler.

Comment: Indeed, not only are those functions not needed, they make things worse; they make it harder for the compiler to check whether the functions cover all cases (exhaustiveness checking).

Comment: the idea is that when you write a function that consumes a union type like your `Tree` type, the compiler can warn you when you write functions that don't cover all of the subcases of the type, which helps catch situations where you forgot one of the type's subcases.  It's a simple thing, but it saves hours of frustration...